# Cannot set value inside drop down list using ng-repeat in Angular.js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I cannot set the value inside drop down list using AngularJS.  My code is below:

```
<select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple">
 <option value=" ">Select Voucher Code</option>
<option value="{{c.value}}" ng-repeat="c in listOfCode">{{c.name}}</option>
 </select>

$scope.listOfCode=[];
        var code={'voucher_code_id':voucherid};
        $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:"php/getVoucherNotifyCode.php",
            data:code,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            //console.log('voucher code',response.data);
            $scope.codeImage=response.data[0].image;
            $scope.arrCode=response.data[0].generated_code.split(',');
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.arrCode.length;i++){
                var data={'name':$scope.arrCode[i],'value':$scope.arrCode[i]};
                $scope.listOfCode.push(data);
            }
            console.log('list of code',$scope.listOfCode);
        },function errorCallback(response) {
        })

$('#lstFruits').multiselect({
           includeSelectAllOption: true
 });
```

Here I am not getting all values in drop down list.

Comment: why `ngOptions` directive is not used?

Comment: Does your $http return success response? Does multiselect need to re-render after update value?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/EsQsW/358/

Comment: yes, $http returns the success response and muplti select need to render.

Comment: @vp_arth : i have already followed this link,here no check box available.

Comment: Does `$scope.listOfCode` contain the data?

Comment: @shammelburg : Yes,its containing the data when removed `$('#lstFruits').multiselect({
           includeSelectAllOption: true
 });` its coming properly but i need the mupltiple select.

Comment: @vp_arth's fiddle allows you to selected multiple values.

Comment: i know that but in that case one has to press ctrl button to select multiple value no check box available.

Comment: use an unordered list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108157/discussion-between-satya-and-shammelburg).